# Whenever I start my pygame game, i get this error

Tags: python, events, int, pygame, callable

I have been following a youtube series on how to make a game in pygame, and I keep getting this error about the QUIT event, and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Brady/Desktop/Python Programs/Climber.py", line 31, in <module>
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Here is the code:

```
#Imports

import pygame
import sys
import random
import cx_Freeze

#Variables

playerhealth = 100

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0 ,255, 0)

#Functions



#Initialization

pygame.init()
gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Climber")

#Game Loop

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    gamedisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Please help me with this error, and any other errors that are in the code.

Comment: Whats on line 31 of `Climber.py`?

Comment: @jm_____ if event.type == pygame.QUIT():

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pygame.QUIT`. It's an integer constant not a function.

e.g

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```